# Using JavaMail to acesse the Calendar's Exchange

Tags: calendar, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

someone know how i can get the meetings and events registered in the Calendar of MS Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

For Office 365, you can use [Office 365 REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations).  See http://dev.outlook.com to get started.   If you are working with Exchange server installed on-premises, you can use [EWS Java API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api).